# "view page source" Page not starting with <!Doctype html>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, doctype

I'm intergrating openId in already developed code (mvc3/razor)
I changed the default route to Account/LogOn from Home/Index
When I viewed "View page source" from browser(right click), _Layout.cshtml is not rendering.
I can see only LogOn.cshtml in view page source.
I'm getting few errors,
I doubt this can be one of the reasons.

[image]

The diagram is output of "view page source"(by right clicking the browser page during runtime)
I need the the page to look like green box.
Red box is output of my program.

Please help.

Comment: Was `Account/LogOn` designed to be loaded in to a dialog and just results in a `PartialView`?

Comment: Have you added specified layout in Partial View? Does your action return `PartialViewResult`?

Comment: home/index was set as default in route before.Now I change default route to Account and Logon. Logon is not a partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either:

Returning LogOn.cshtm as partial from your action method (i.e., return Partial();)

or

Not specifying layout view for your LogOn.cshtm. If this is the case, specify a layout view in the _ViewStart.cshtml so that it applies to all pages by default OR specify it in the LogOn.cshtm itself using @ { Layout = "~/_Your-Layout-View.cshtml" } directive.